# Using ES2015 classes in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined

in meteor 1.2 (actually just updated to 1.2.0.2) with a class defined in lib from a server file.

```
class MyClass {
 // lots of OOP code here .....
}
```

Do you have to do something special for meteor to pick up the new ES2015 class stuff? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the class global, like

```js
MyClass = class MyClass { /*...*/ };
```

Since Meteor wraps all your .js files in IIFOs

**As of Meteor 1.3**
You should declare your class in `imports/.../myClass.js` as follows:

```js
export class MyClass {
  /* ... */
}
```

And whereever you want to use it:

```js
import {MyClass} from 'imports/.../myClass';
/* ... */
MyClass.something();
```